# How can I reuse the where condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a required business logic that should get the product price from the `PriceList` table. You can see in the code that some parts of the query are repeated.

I'm concerned about how I could reuse some parts of the query: `p.Sellers.Any(s => s.PersonId == personID)` or `currentDate >= p.StartDate && currentDate <= p.EndDate` for example.

```
var basicQuery = context.PriceList.Where(p => !p.Deleted);

// first search by product, salesman and date
var priceItem = basicQuery.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productID && 
                                               p.Sellers.Any(s => s.PersonId == personID) &&
                                               currentDate >= p.StartDate &&
                                               currentDate <= p.EndDate);

if(priceItem != null)
   return priceItem;

priceItem = basicQuery.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productID && 
                                           currentDate >= p.StartDate &&
                                           currentDate <= p.EndDate);

if(priceItem != null)
   return priceItem;    

priceItem = basicQuery.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productID && 
                                           p.Sellers.Any(s => s.PersonId == personID));


if(priceItem != null)
   return priceItem;

priceItem = basicQuery.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productID);

return priceItem;
```

Comment: Make a method and call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all conditions are joined with AND in your example - you can reuse them like this:

```
Expression<Func<Price,bool>> sellerFilter = 
    (p) => p.Sellers.Any(s => s.PersonId == personID);
Expression<Func<Price,bool>> dateFilter = 
    (p) => currentDate >= p.StartDate && currentDate <= p.EndDate;

var priceItem = basicQuery
    .Where(sellerFilter)
    .Where(dateFilter)
    .Where(p => p.ProductId == productId)
    .FirstOrDefault(); //etc
```

If you had more complex conditions than just a chain of ANDs - it will be a bit more tricky.

Comment: It looks like what I'm looking for. I'll test it

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by pushing `p.ProductId == productID` into `basicQuery`, because it is part of a conjunction in all four variations:

```
var basicQuery = context.PriceList.Where(p => !p.Deleted && p.ProductId == productID);
```

After that I would create two expressions - by seller and by date:

```
Expression<Func<Product,bool>> bySeller = p =>
    p.Sellers.Any(s => s.PersonId == personID);
Expression<Func<Product,bool>> byDate = p =>
    currentDate >= p.StartDate && currentDate <= p.EndDate);
```

Now you can use these two expressions in your `Where` clauses,

```
var priceItem = basicQuery.Where(bySeller).Where(byDate).FirstOrDefault();
if (priceItem != null) return priceItem;
var priceItem = basicQuery.Where(byDate).FirstOrDefault();
if (priceItem != null) return priceItem;
var priceItem = basicQuery.Where(bySeller).FirstOrDefault();
return basicQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

or use null coalesce to remove `if`s:

```
return basicQuery.Where(bySeller).Where(byDate).FirstOrDefault()
    ?? basicQuery.Where(byDate).FirstOrDefault()
    ?? basicQuery.Where(bySeller).FirstOrDefault()
    ?? basicQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```